# Comma after time expressions

Tags: punctuation, time-words

Should a comma be put after time expressions when they are used at the beginning of a sentence? Is there any particular rule to follow?

Last Sunday(,) all members of the Brown family were at home.

Comment: Commas correspond to how something it is. Generally, that phrase would be at the end. If you place it at the beginning, the comma shows a pause where you intonation drops.

Comment: There would be no pause and no comma before sentences where **Last Sunday** (or similar) served as the subject. Last Sunday was the most beautiful day of the year.

Comment: What Ronald Sole said, and to add that when a time expression is used as an adverbial of time, there should probably be a comma after it. Without the natural pause indicated by the comma, it sounds like the speaker is too excited to pause there.